# How does the measurement info work in IBM quantum lab?

Tags: quantum-gate

How exactly does the measurment info work in the IBM Quantum Lab.
[image: measurment info image]

This is my quantum circuit.
A simple Hadamard gate on q[0]
[image: circuit]

When I use the measuremnt on c[0] it shows
[image: result]

and when I use it on c[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPtw4.png) it shows
[image: result]

Can someone explain this, i'm fairly new to Quantum Computing

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using two qubits, it automatically assigns two classical bits to store the measurement results even though you are doing nothing to the second qubit.

The initial state of your qubits is $|00\rangle$. Then you are applying $H$ on the first qubit and doing nothing to the second qubit, i.e., applying $I_2 \otimes H_1$ and thus your resultant state is

$$ |00\rangle \xrightarrow{I_2 \otimes H_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg(|00\rangle + |01\rangle \bigg) $$

Your classical bits are also $0$ initially. When you measure 1st qubit, i.e., right one in the braket notation, $50\%$ of the time you get $0$ and $50\%$ of the time you get $1$ and thus when you store the result in `c[0]`, `c[1]` = $0$ and `c[0]` is $0$ or $1$ thus reading both bits written as `c[1] c[0]` gives you $00$ or $01$. When you store the result in the `c[1]` classical bit, `c[1]` bit becomes $0$ or $1$ and `c[0]` bit stays $0$, and thus you get $00$ or $10$.